# Data Transfer from NFC app to PN532 reader

Tags: android, nfc, payment, nfc-p2p, hce

i m working on final year project of nfc based payment , i m stucked here coz i read on net that you cant transfer data (say credit card details) from NFC phone to PN532 reader ..i read about P2P mode to transfer data but i m not getting an exact idea how to do that..is any method to transfer card details from Phone Application to NFC reader??
i m just at the starting of the project , currently i m gathering all infos regarding my project! but i cant transfer data from phone to reader then my project would fail!

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a PN532 as the other end of the communication, I would suggest that you use the PN532 in card emulation mode. You can then access it from the phone as if it was an IsoDep card. See, for instance, the paper ["An NFC ticketing system with a new approach of an inverse reader mode"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/NFC.2013.6482448).

As an alternative you coud do peer-to-peer communication (note, however, that particularly bi-directional communication with an Android device is not that straight forward and involves a lot of communication overhead). The [ISMB-SNEP](http://code.google.com/p/ismb-snep-java/) project, for instance, shows how to implement communication between an Android device and an ACR122U (which contains a PN532).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I used the stickynotes app from android, and tried to transfer the NDEF message to my NFC module in arduino. Though I did managed to read the phone's info (ID, etc) using this repository https://github.com/Seeed-Shield/NFC_Shield_DEV

Comment: which board are u using with pn532?? arduino uno?